# Change profile of ALL Terminator terminals at once

Tags: command-line, themes, terminator

When using terminator, I tend to have multiple terminals open in the same window (splitting horizontally/vertically and with tabs).

If I right-click on one of those terminals and change the profile, only that terminal changes its profile, the rest are kept the same, as seen in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Tps.png)

What I'd like is to have a way of changing all of them at once (preferably with a keyboard shortcut). Do you know of any way of doing this?